# Does remote control 8879 work for winter holiday train?

Tags: trains, power-functions

Can anyone tell me if the remote control 8879 will actually stop and start the 10254 Winter Holiday Train set?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, essentially it was designed for applications like trains since it has an option to increase power gradually, unlike 8885 controller which is ON-OFF (basically with two speed settings - "9" and "0"). You can do this by turning orange disks to start moving your train. There are 9 "speeds" in each direction. And you have two options then to stop your train:

1. Hit red button below the disk to stop immediately;
2. Return disk to zero speed position.

The remote controller you are asking about is one of the items required to motorize the entire set as seen on the picture below. This is taken from [instructions](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/buildinginstructions/10254) for 10254 Winter Holiday Train set.

[image]

Comment: This is all correct, assuming OP has a Power Functions train motor, battery box and IR receiver built into his train. None of the LEGO Christmas trains come with those supplied, they need to be purchased separately. Might be worth mentioning in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

10254 doesn't come with a motor. If you motorize it using the "recommended" Power Functions parts, that is the correct remote to use. If you motorize it using the newer Powered Up [train motor](https://rebrickable.com/sets/88011-1/train-motor/) and [battery box](https://rebrickable.com/parts/28738/powered-up-hub-battery-box/), you need [88010](https://rebrickable.com/sets/88010-1/remote-control) to control the Powered Up Hub.